# LISP clause for and clause let ¿why?,making a programming language in racket using ragg

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, dr.racket

I have long been trying to find the error, I'm doing a programming language and have the next code, using ragg, I have a syntax-object(resto ...) what has a bracket as data, I transform this syntax-object to a datum:

```
   (let ([i (syntax->datum #'(resto ...))])
           (display "Content i:")
            (display i)
           (if (eq? i (string->symbol "(})"))
               (display "true")
               (display "false")
            )
   )
```

and the output is:

```
Content: (})
false
```

But if I do this

```
   (for ([i (syntax->datum #'(resto ...))])
     (displayln "Content:")
     (displayln i)
     (if (eq? i (string->symbol "}"))
           (display "true")
           (display "false")
     )
   )
```

and the output is:

```
Content: }
true
```

**MY QUESTION: 
¿WHY THE IF OF CLAUSE LET IS FALSE?
¿AS I CAN COMPARE THESE TWO TYPES AND THAT THE RESULT IS TRUE WITHOUT THE FOR?**

Documentation about functions:

[syntax->datum](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxops.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._syntax-~3edatum%29%29)

Comment: Perhaps you should include a sample of the input you wish to parse, I have the feeling that you're doing this more complicated than needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each piece of code is doing a very different thing, I'll show you how to make each one work. The first one uses `let` to assign into a variable the whole list returned by `syntax->datum`, and afterwards you compare it against another list (better use `equal?` for testing equality, it's more general):

```
(let ([i (syntax->datum #'(|}|))]) ; `i` contains `(})`
  (display "Content i: ")
  (displayln i)
  (if (equal? i '(|}|)) ; a list with a single element, the symbol `}`
      (displayln "true")
      (displayln "false")))
```

The second piece of code is using `for` to iterate over each element in a list, until it finds the symbol `}`:

```
(for ([i (syntax->datum #'(|}|))]) ; `i` contains `}`
  (display "Content i: ")
  (displayln i)
  (if (equal? i '|}|) ; the symbol `}`
      (displayln "true")
      (displayln "false")))
```

As a side note, you have to be very careful with the way you're going to process all those curly brackets `{}` in your language, they're interpreted as normal parentheses `()` in Racket and they'll be tricky to handle, notice how I had to escape them by surrounding them with vertical bars.